# Match string with prefix and suffix use Logstash grok pattern

Tags: regex, logstash-grok

I have a ELK cluster to keep my logs below, and i want to extract some fields in the log use logstash grok.

```
[info ][170703 10:34:38.998686/832]acct ok,deal_time=122ms;ACCESS_PORT=216179383538692472&ACCESS_TYPE=2&ACCOUNT=07592111916&Acct-Status-Type=3;
```

here is my grok pattern.

```
%{SYSLOG5424SD}\[%{DATA:[@metadata][timestamp]}\/%{NUMBER}\]%{WORD:type}\ %{WORD:status}\,%{GREEDYDATA}%{NUMBER:dealtime}ms\;%{GREEDYDATA}(?<acct>(?<=ACCOUNT=).*)
```

i want to extract some field's value and give it to the event variable.
eg. acct = 07592111916

i use (?(?<=ACCOUNT=).*&$) to extract the value, but not works, where is my problem?

i debug the code in this site.
http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com

Comment: Does the answer below work for you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes, it works.

Comment: If you have another question please post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to extract this way:

`(?<acct>(?<=ACCOUNT=)[^&]+)`

Comment: thanks, it works. how can i go further, for example, check if the "ACCOUNT=" string exists, if not skip the pattern.